# How to solve for multiple user ids when saving a file to temp file path using VBA

Tags: vba

The code below creates a temp file on any employee's system whose user ID begins with "PA" (then in J2 whoever is running the code enters the numbers to their user ID - Example ID would be PA11111) this way anyone can use the file. However employees in other locations do not have a user ID that start with a "PA" but instead other characters.

How can I make this code more dynamic so that any of our employees can run the file?

```
sTempPath = "C:\Users\PA" & Worksheets("Print_Results_Auto").Range("J2") & "\AppData\Local\Temp\"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the windows login info in vba using:

```
cUser = Environ$("Username")
```

Then I would do:

```
sTempPath = "C:\Users\" & cUser  & "\AppData\Local\Temp\"
```

Enviorn$("Username") should get the windows login user and that should be the user id that is in the file path.

Answer (score 0):

```
sTempPath = Environ$("Temp")
```

This is the link to the local temp file. No need to enter any user ID in the sheet.